# In the given figure end A is connected to positive terminal and B with negative terminal of a 10 volts battery. How exactly will the current flow?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

Further in my textbook it is stated that the ends of all three resistors are under the same potential difference. how is that possible?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/100352/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting if resistances are parallel or series in complex circuits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79225/)

Answer (score 0):

A is at 10V and is connected by a (perfect 0-resistance, so no voltage drop across it) wire to 2, so 2 is at 10V. B is at 0V and is connected by a wire to 1, so 1 is at 0V. So the potential difference across the $6\Omega$ resistor is the difference between A and 1: 10V. The potential difference across the $15\Omega$ resistor is the difference between 2 and B: 10V. The potential difference across the $10\Omega$ resistor is the difference between 2 and 1: 10V. Now use Ohm's law to find the current through each resistor.

Comment: can you explain with kircoff's law how the current splits in the circuit. I think no current should be flowing in the 6 ohm resistor since there is an alternative wire which offers no resistance but it is wrong. please explain

Comment: There is current through every resistor: the "alternative wire" has a 10Ω resistor on it before it gets to B, so your intuition is wrong. It *is* a good exercise to see that all the currents add up properly at every junction, but I'm not going to do that for you: you should be able to do it yourself now. One thing to watch out for is the *direction* of the currents. In your diagram, the current through the 10Ω resistor goes from *right* to *left* (the high voltage is at 2 and the low voltage is at 1).