# 3 resistances in series shunted from the sides

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance

[image]

How to find the equivalent resistance of the given circuit?

Comment: It seems this was asked [before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79225/detecting-if-resistances-are-parallel-or-series-in-complex-circuits)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here's a visual way: if the resistances are "stretched out", they become parallel. So the equivalent resistance is $\frac R3$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume potential at any node, the resistances with the same potential across them are in parallel.
Or you can simply just name the nodes and the nodes which are at the same potential can be treated as the same point.

[image]

[image]