# Why are the resistors considered to be connected in parallel in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

in the first part (i) i am not able to understand why these resistors are considered that they are parallel.  is because of the joints?

[image]

Comment: What is the voltage across each resistor in terms of $V_{AB}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79225/2451